# Using Eclipse with non-standard subversion directory layouts

Tags: eclipse, svn, subversive

I have a subversion repository with a layout like this:

```
/trunk/<projectname>
/branches/<projectname>/<branchname>
/tags/<projectname>/<tagname>
```

It is this way for historical reasons, which aren't really up for debate and so I won't go into here.

I'm trying to use this layout with Eclipse (Juno) using the Subversive plug in. The .project file lives in `/trunk/<projectname>`, and I can check out a project from trunk with no problem.  However if I try to create a new branch for a project using subversive, I seem to get into trouble. Creating a branch with a path `/branches/<projectname>/<branchname>`, it gets transformed into a branch `/branches/<projectname>/<branchname>/<projectname>`.

The repository properties dialog has no visible options which allow for this layout - although the Advanced tab has fields for "Resource names" which default to as "trunk", "branches" and "tags", these evidently cannot contain a path separator without being rejected as an "invalid resource name"

I've read the documentation for Subversive. It talks about a ["Repository Location project layout"](http://www.eclipse.org/subversive/documentation/teamSupport/layouts.php), and states that with this *"the user is free to change this layout by any way he wish" [sic]* - but it doesn't really explain how.

In short What's the correct, or most expedient way to use this layout within Eclipse?

Note, I really need a way which will appease those users uncomfortable with the command line subversion client, so dropping to the command line won't be a very satisfactory solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been answered on the Eclipse Subversive forum here:

http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/mv/msg/674039/1274614/#msg_1274614

To quote:

> It is not the one of recommended layouts, so the automation is not available for it. In order to use such a layout you should open plug-in preferences and change the following option: Window->Preferences->Team->SVN->Project structure->Branch and Tag settings from "Respect project structure" to "Manual specification"

I have checked and it does seem to work, although unfortunately it is a global setting and not a per-project setting.

Answer (score 0):

I have not used it, and I'm not using eclipse for branching/merging operations, but in Window/Preferences/Team/SVN > project structure, you can modify project structure.
Not sure exaclty what it do , but you can try playing with structure settings and manual specification.

Command line subversion don't really assume a structure, given a tag/branch is only a simple (remote preferably) copy, so you may be able to just copy from Eclipse (IIRC it's possible in the repositories view).

Comment: Thanks - I hadn't found that. Saying that, although the "Project Structure" tab section "Structure Settings" includes fields for "trunk", "tags" and "branches", I still have the same issue I described above, in that any attempt to add a path separator "/" is disallowed.  I can't yet see any other settings which would help....

Comment: Later: you were essentially right, although I didn't understand that "manual specification" was a literal checkbox name and not manually editing a field. I am still baffled by the documentation for [project structure](http://www.eclipse.org/subversive/documentation/teamSupport/layouts.php).